# Rotational invariant hash function for binary matrix

Tags: matrix, hash, binary, rotation

I am looking for a hash function that will assign a scalar value for a small binary matrix(7x7). I want it to give different values for 2 different matrices  unless one matrix is a 90 degree,180 degree or 270 degree rotation of the other one.
    Do you have any suggestions on how I could do this? I was expecting to find a method in image processing as this would be equivalent to a 7x7 binary image but I could not find anything.

Comment: In the worst case, you could compute all four rotations of the matrix, take whichever one is lexicographically first, then hash that with a standard hash function. This essentially gives you a "canonical form" for the matrix, which is independent of the hashing idea.

Comment: thank you, taking the minimum is actually really good.

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment to an answer:

If you're trying to find a way to test if two objects are equivalent after doing some sort of transformation, it often helps to pick a single "canonical form" for the object that can easily be computed. In your case, it would probably help a lot to pick a single rotation of the matrix as the "canonical" rotation and compare things that way. One simple option would be to pick the lexicographically first matrix out of all the rotations possible, then use that.